# mysql - I can't point foreign key to datetime field type

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1005

I have 2 tables called mEmpl and mOrder.

mEmpl has 9 fields:

> IDEmployee (int), ShortName (varchar), Name (varchar), DBegin (datetime primary key), DEnd (datetime primary key), Directory (varchar), Mode (varchar primary key), PartTime (varchar), IDJob (int)

mOrder has 11 fields:

> IDOrder (int), NrOrder (int), OrderDesc (varchar), IDOwner (int), Budget (float), DBegin (datetime), DEnd (datetime), Mode (varchar), ArtCost (int), BaseRate (int), BaseItem (int)

When I try to add a foreign key at `mOrder(DBegin, DEnd, and Mode)` which references mEmpl, it always raises an error message:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'spezet.#sql-4d4_1' (errno: 150)
```

However, if I just add a foreign key to DBegin like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mOrder ADD FOREIGN KEY (DBegin) REFERENCES mEmpl(DBegin);
```

it's not raising any error! The DBegin is successfully pointing to the mEmpl.DBegin primary key.

Can anyone describe to me what's wrong here or whether MySQL indeed can't point to 2 datetime fields at once? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Which storage engine are you using?

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for each table and post it here.

Comment: Brian: I'm use InnoDB Engine..
tombom: Thanks a lot, I'll try that query..

Answer (score 2):

You can find more details of the cause of the problem by logging in to MySQL as root and entering:-

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

This may prove helpful. I suspect the cause of the problem is that when creating a foreign key, you need an index on the referenced table that contains the referenced columns as the first columns of the index, in the order specified in the foreign key constraint.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for more.

Comment: These days, mysql generally creates the required indexes on FK-involved fields automatically.

Comment: @MarcB, yes, MySQL Workbench certainly does that.

Comment: Thanks for all great answers from expert programmer like you all.. I've been resolving this problem with adding any index to my referenced fields. Best Regard!